# Unity Google Play default leaderboard all players (not only friends)?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, leaderboard

I have integrated google play game servises to my unity game.
When i call PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ShowLeaderboardUI() i get my leaderboard, which is set to show only friends scores by default. To see all scores i have to tap switcher. Is there any way to show scores of all players by default?
Thanks!

Comment: you simply have to use **a plug in**, which you can get from the asset store for a few dollars, or very likely find a free one.  simply google "unity3d plugin google play leaderboards" for 100s of solutions.  for professional use in major games, the best is Prime31.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do do it with the current Unity Built in function. You need to make android plugin for that.

Comment: well i gues this task is too difficult for me. Thank you!